# other way for my school project

Tags: c++

Good day! I'm making a global currency exchanger.

```
const string currency_name[MAX_CURRENCY] = 
{
    "Euro",
    "Pound",
    "Dollar",
};

const double exchange_rate[MAX_CURRENCY][MAX_CURRENCY] = 
{
    { 1, 0.795833, 1.33943 },   // Euro->Euro, Euro->pound, euro->dollar
    { 1.25657, 1, 1.68296 },    // Pound->Euro, Pound->Pound, Pound->Dollar
                                // will add 15 by 15 global currency exchange
};
```

I'm currently using this.
Are there any solutions easier than this??

Comment: The exchange rate is subjected to change. So It will be better to pick this from database, where you updates the latest exchange rates, at-least once in a day.

Comment: Are you after easier or better solutions?

Comment: Off-topic and unclear. You need to show an [MCVE], so improve your question to show one. You could use some [container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)

Comment: database? im just learning stage right now :/

Comment: @gjijo where can i learn using database easily :/

Comment: You might use [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) for your database (or some [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDBMS) server like [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org/)...). Read some SQL tutorial. You'll need some [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) client library like [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) to fill it with real exchange rates (and you'll need to find some web service publishing them). That might be too ambitious for a newbie.

Comment: this is just a school project for extra credit LOL

Comment: Then at least use some container in your homework. Perhaps use some [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

Answer (score 0):

Defining currency exchange rates as data type is a good idea. And I don't see what other data type may fit better than simple matrix. So, your solution is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Pick one currency as the "reference currency".
Then you only need conversions to and from this regardless of how many currencies you have.
You can also limit yourself to one direction, since it's easy to find the inverse.

Example:

```
enum Currency
{
    Euro,
    Pound,
    Dollar,
    ...
};

// The conversion rate into Euro.
const float euroRates[] = { 1.0, 1.25657, ... };

float into_euro(float amount, Currency c) { return amount * euroRates[c]; }
float from_euro(float amount, Currency c) { return amount / euroRates[c]; }

float convert(float amount, Currency from, Currency to)
{
    return from_euro(into_euro(amount, from), to);
}
```

Comment: enum is new to me so ill pass ...  and i got 15 currencies to convert vice versa so 15x15 @@

Comment: @newbie The enum isn't important, you can ditch it and keep the idea of  a reference currency so you don't need the 15x15 table.

Comment: i have a solution here
currency1(convert from),currency2(convert to),amount,value
is this similar to yours